# Clarify C# Extension Method Precedence

Tags: c#

I'm trying to modify the behaviour of an existing extension method by creating my own extension method with the same name. I know this is possible as long as the method signature is different. I also know that which method to call is based on how *close* the signature is.

If I have

```
public void DoStuff(this List<string> list) {
    //...
}
```

and

```
public void DoStuff<T>(this List<T> list) {
    //...
}
```

I know that `DoStuff` will be called for `new List<string>().DoStuff()`, while `DoStuff<T>` will be called for `new List<int>().DoStuff()`.

What I don't understand is why I'm not seeing the same behaviour when I'm using an interface.

```
public interface IBar { }

public class Foo : IBar
{

}

public static class FooHelper
{
    public static void DoStuff(this IBar stuff)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("public static void DoStuff (this IBar stuff)");
    }

    public static void DoStuff<T>(this T stuff)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("public static void DoStuff<T>(this T stuff)");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        foo.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

In the example above, I expected `public static void DoStuff (this IBar stuff)` to the output, however I get `public static void DoStuff<T>(this T stuff)`.
I assumed that the interface type is more specific than a generic type, and therefor a better choice for my `DoStuff` call.

Why does the generic type signature get chosen over the interface type signature?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the spec says but I would assume that its because the generic one can match exactly (T = Foo is an exact match) whereas IBar requires some inference. If you actually declare foo as an IBar (ie `IBar foo = new Foo();`) then it will do what you want. I suspect you just need to read the rules in the c# spec for overloading to discover exactly why it chooses one over the other. If you want to know why the design choice was made then that is another matter... AS a last note I think Eric Lippert has written some articles on overload resolution that may cover this.

Comment: As a further note this is not related to them being extension methods. If you called them as normal methods you would get the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My thinking was along those lines too. I also found Eric Lippert's articles and they were very helpful.

Comment: all of eric's articles are really helpful. Sadly he posts less I think than when he was at microsoft but its well worth spending time flicking through all his posts and reading anything that looks even half interesting to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris' comment is correct, below are some more details from C# Language Specification:

Calling extension method `foo.DoStuff()` is equivalent to calling static method `FooHelper.DoStuff(foo)`.

The compiler has to determine the exact method to invoke (§7.6.5.1 Method invocations). First it will create a set of candidate methods. Both DoStuff methods will be in this set, because

> o If F is non-generic, F is a candidate when:
>
> • M has no type argument list, and
>
> • F is applicable with respect to A (§7.5.3.1).
>
> o  If F is generic and M has no type argument list, F is a candidate when:
>
> • Type inference (§7.5.2) succeeds, inferring a list of type arguments for the call, and
>
> • Once the inferred type arguments are substituted for the corresponding method type parameters, all constructed types in the parameter list of F satisfy their constraints (§4.4.4), and the parameter list of F is applicable with respect to A (§7.5.3.1).

The generic `FooHelper.DoStuff` method will already have the type parameter inferred (§7.5.2):

> Type inference occurs as part of the binding-time processing of a method invocation (§7.6.5.1) and takes place before the overload resolution step of the invocation.
>
> If type inference succeeds, then the inferred type arguments are used to determine the types of arguments for subsequent overload resolution.

So the candidate set is

```
public static void DoStuff(this IBar stuff)
public static void DoStuff<Foo>(this Foo stuff)
```

From this set the compiler will choose the best method to call. The rules are described in §7.5.3.2. In this case, the generic method will be called, because identity conversion (from Foo to Foo) is better than conversion from Foo to IBar.

Comment: Thank you. My understanding of how generic types get handled is where my thought process went wrong. This explanation has helped me.

Comment: Good stuff. I tried to find stuff in the spec but I think the spec I was using was out of date (google turns up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645597(v=vs.71).aspx which has VS 2003 at the top so I suspect was an earlier version, probably pre-generics). Thanks for fleshing out my thoughts though. :)

Comment: @Chris You're welcome. The C# language spec is installed with Visual Studio in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\1033